# I have an excel sheet which has four columns in which each cell of the column is related to the next columns cell in a cascaded manner

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have an excel sheet which has four columns  in which each cell of the column is related to the next columns cell in a cascaded manner.

The excel sheet looks like below:-

```
  Base Version   OS Package Name             Description  Version
0            A  NaN          NaN                     NaN      NaN
1          NaN    B          NaN                     NaN      NaN
2          NaN  NaN     b-01.zip  description about B-01      NaN
3          NaN  NaN     b-02.zip  description about B-02      NaN
4            X  NaN          NaN                     NaN      NaN
5          NaN    Y          NaN                     NaN      NaN
6          NaN  NaN     y-01.zip  description about Y-01      NaN
7          NaN  NaN     y-02.zip  description about Y-02      NaN
```

I want to have a DataFrame that should look like below when output to an excel sheet.

```
  Base Version   OS Package Name             Description  Version
2            A    B     b-01.zip  description about B-01      NaN
3          NaN  NaN     b-02.zip  description about B-02      NaN
6            X    Y     y-01.zip  description about Y-01      NaN
7          NaN  NaN     y-02.zip  description about Y-02      NaN
```

Is there a way in Pandas to achieve this?

Comment: Please provide your data as a [mre] (i.e as **text** not image)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [`ffill`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.ffill.html) and [boolean indexing](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/user_guide/indexing.html#boolean-indexing):

```
# identify rows with data
m = df['Package Name'].notna()

# ffill and keep first value
df[['Base Version', 'OS']] = df[['Base Version', 'OS']].ffill()[m].drop_duplicates()

# only select the rows of interest
df = df[m]
```

Alternative if you want a copy:

```
m = df['Package Name'].notna()
out = df[m]
out.loc[:, ['Base Version', 'OS']] = (df[['Base Version', 'OS']].ffill()
                                      [m].drop_duplicates()
                                     )
```

Output:

```
  Base Version   OS Package Name             Description  Version
2            A    B     b-01.zip  description about B-01      NaN
3          NaN  NaN     b-02.zip  description about B-02      NaN
6            X    Y     y-01.zip  description about Y-01      NaN
7          NaN  NaN     y-02.zip  description about Y-02      NaN
```

Reproducible input:

```
from numpy import nan

df = pd.DataFrame({'Base Version': ['A', nan, nan, nan, 'X', nan, nan, nan],
                   'OS': [nan, 'B', nan, nan, nan, 'Y', nan, nan],
                   'Package Name': [nan, nan, 'b-01.zip', 'b-02.zip', nan, nan, 'y-01.zip', 'y-02.zip'],
                   'Description': [nan, nan, 'description about B-01', 'description about B-02', nan, nan, 'description about Y-01', 'description about Y-02'],
                   'Version': [nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan]})
```

Answer (score 0):

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
# reading excel sheet
file=pd.read_excel("input_excel.xlsx")
# rotating the OS column elements in anticlockwise - 1time
file["OS"]=np.roll(np.array(file["OS"]),-1)
# rotating the Package name elements in anticlockwise - 2times
file["Package Name"]=np.roll(np.array(file["Package Name"]),-2)
# rotating the Description elements in anticlockwise - 2times
file["Description"]=np.roll(np.array(file["Description"]),-2) 
# removing rows which only contain Nan and exporting them to excel 
file.dropna(how='all').to_excel("output_excel.xlsx", index=False)
```

**Remember to change the following:**

- Input and output file name or file location
- Check column names
- No of times to rotate

[image]